# Why does my Java "for" loop immediately end?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

My first loop seems to build the array correctly and when I go to print out the results in the second "for" loop it immediately terminates. I cannot see the error. Here is the code:

```
public class CoinFlip 
{
    private static int Flip()
    {
        return (int)(2*Math.random());   //returns 0 or 1; 0=Tails,1=Heads 
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int HEADS = 1;
        int[] ConsecArray = new int[1000];   // the odds of ever having more than 1000 HEADS consecutively flipped are nil
        int Sequencecounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ConsecArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (Flip() == HEADS)
            {
                Sequencecounter++;
            }
            else    // we have a TAILS
            {
                // Check sequence counter, if > 0, logging to do...
                if (Sequencecounter > 0)
                {
                    // Update length counters
                    int index = Sequencecounter - 1; 
                    ConsecArray[index]++;
                    Sequencecounter = 0;
                }
                    // consecutive tails, continue in loop
            }
        }
        int j = ConsecArray.length;
        System.out.println("Length" + "     " + "NumberRunsOfHeads");
        for (int k = 0; k == j; k++)
        {
            int index = k + 1;
            String bucketName =  Integer.toString(index);
            String bucketValue = Integer.toString(ConsecArray[k]);
            System.out.println(bucketName + "     " + bucketValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but in `Flip()` you should be caching a Random instance and calling `nextBoolean()`. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first iteration of your 2nd loop:
k is 0
j is 1000
the test k == j fails
the loop never runs

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for (int k = 0; k == j; k++)
```

into

```
for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean either `k <= j` or `k < j`, but you put `k == j`.  This is not true during first iteration, so loop body never executes.

```
    for (int k = 0; k == j; k++)
    {
        int index = k + 1;
        String bucketName =  Integer.toString(index);
        String bucketValue = Integer.toString(ConsecArray[k]);
        System.out.println(bucketName + "     " + bucketValue);
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure it'll be "k < j" since he's calling j the length of ConsecArray (just FYI if he checks this answer).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for (int k = 0; k == j; k++)` (which is equivalent to `if (k == j)`) you meant to write or `for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)`, i.e. loop j times, not loop as long as `k == j`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
for (int k = 0; k == j; k++)
```

Should be this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

kett_chup is right. I Think you want "k < j". You're thinking of "until" rather than "for".